# Study differentiability of a multi variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}$. Study the differentiability of the function at the point $(0,1).$

I know that the derivative of a multi variable function is calculated as follows:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac {\|f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)-J(h)\|_{\mathbb R}}{\|h\|_{\mathbb{R}^2}}$$

How do I actually use this on this function?

Comment: That's *not* the definition. What you wrote doesn't make sense. Is $h$ a real number or an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It's on the wikipedia page ......... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: My guess is, it's an element of $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: If it's an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then what's the meaning of $x+h$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right, I know, but I have no idea, I just want to study the differentiability and that's the definition I found on that site

Comment: What you wrote here is **not** what's to be found on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: You must know that $\;J\;$ is a linear transformation and you can drop the indexes $\;\Bbb R\;$ as we must understand the meaning of those norms

Comment: and that $\;h\;$ is a vector , so the definition (Wiki's, say) must be understood as $\;f(x+h_1,y+h_2)\;$ , with $\;h=(h_1,h_2)\;$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the partial derivatives at $\;(0,1)\;$:

$$\begin{cases}f'_x=\cfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}\implies f'_x(0,1)=...\text{doesn't exist}\\{}\\
f'(y)=\frac {y-1}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}\implies f'_y(0,1)=...\text{ doesn't exist}\end{cases}$$

and thus $\;f\;$ cannot be differentiable at $\;(0,1)\;$

Comment: What if one partial derivative exists and the other does not exist?

Comment: The function still isn't differentiable at that point.